# half-upgraded unbootable Ubuntu box

Tags: ubuntu, boot, upgrade

While I was upgrading from Ubuntu 9.04 to 9.10, the box lost power (I think while it was paused at one of those stupid prompts about whether to replace a config file!).  Now it hangs during the boot.  The last message is:

/proc/bus/usb: waiting for none

Now what?

Answer (score 3):

you could try booting from a Live CD and using chroot to get an operable shell in the unbootable system, from which you could finish the upgrade. Or you could boot a Live CD, plug in an external hard drive, copy all your data off of the computer, and reinstall.

Comment: The chroot is a great idea!  I'll try it!

Comment: needed to do this first: http://www.knoppix.net/wiki/Dev_null_permission_denied

Comment: Oh yeah, the bind mount thing.